# How can I use speech_recognition in python3 in the Mac (I downloaded but PyAudio not found)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I downloaded the speech_recognition module for python3, and I have python3 running in Atom in my Mac. Now I'm trying to run this program:

```
# Responds to a name
# https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/

import re
import speech_recognition

# Obtain audio from the microphone
recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = recognizer.listen(source)

# Recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
words = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)

# Respond to speech
matches = re.search("my name is (.*)", words)
if matches and "hello" in words:
    print(f"Hey, {matches[1]}.")
elif matches and "goodbye" in words:
    print("Goodbye, {matches[1]}.")
elif matches and "how are you" in words:
    print("I am well, {matches[1]}, and you?")
else:
    print("Huh?")
```

However, I get this message: `AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation`
But I already downloaded PyAudio, and I actually saw it in my computer, however, it is in Python2's folder in my computer. I tried moving it, but I still can't do it. I want to be able to use the `Microphone` in my code. I would love if you could help :))

Comment: did you install pyaudio via pip? if so you'll have to use `pip3` to install to python 3

Comment: Thank you!!! It worked!!!!!!!!!!!